# How can I force the Pictures app to refresh its library?

Tags: windows-8, pictures

I've imported some pictures to my "My Pictures" folder using Adobe Lightroom, but the Pictures app doesn't seem to notice the new files? Is there some way to force it to refresh its library?

To be clear,

Pictures are sorted under `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures\` by year, then date; for example: `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures\2012\2012-10-20`, these show, however those in `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures\2012\2012-10-29` do not, despite coming from the same camera, being in the same format, thumbnails working in Exporer, the pictures opening in the Pictures app via a double click in explorer, and Windows Media Centre having no problems.

I have tried excluding the Pictures library, and reincluding it, but that had no effect. It has taken three or four reboots for even the folders to show up in the app, but it reports them as empty

Comment: So the images have actually been copied to `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures`, or did you simply add some location to the Pictures Library?

Comment: Strictly speaking, they are in a folder structure `C:\Users\<username>\Pictures\2012\2012-11-03` (and other folders under 2012 show OK)

Comment: Does a logoff/logon or a reboot help refresh the cache?

Comment: @Karan no, have completely shut down/rebooted since adding the newer photos

Comment: do the photos open with the photos app? go to the folder and open those pics with the app. if they don't then that might be the reason

Comment: @PratyushNalam the photos do open with the photos app with no problem

Comment: @RowlandShaw My mistake was thinking you meant the Photos Metro app, when you really did mean the Pictures app.

Comment: @mcandre I do mean the app with the tile titled "Photos", I also am only referring to photos that are on the local disc that will load in same said app if double clicked in Explorer

Comment: I have the same issue. I upgraded my existing win7 and there are many photos in my picture library and none appear in the Photo app. when I click on them in the file explorer they open in the photo app. I have tried to un-install and re-install the photo app and nothing seemsto help

Comment: You need to _import_ the photos in the Photos app right? Like you would inside Lightroom to see any images there... Try the Import command in the Photos app.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund Import explicitly excludes locations that are part of the pictures library for import, so that isn't an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if Windows Search hasn't had a chance to index the photos yet, or the index is corrupt. Rebuilding the index can force the pictures app to rebuild its own index.

to rebuild the index, or ensure the relevant folders are included from the Start screen, type Indexing Options and choose the option of that name that appears under the "settings" section.

If the option doesn't appear, it may be due to the search service having been disabled (for example, to install Outlook 2013 on x64), so it would need to be reinstalled from control panel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it by following the instructions in [the first post in this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-photos-app-not-refreshing-cant-edit/e6d698ee-2bba-4360-9179-00f6e2a5b698): I closed the Windows Photos App, then navigated to the folder

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
```

and deleted its contents. When I started the Photos App again, everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I can get the Photos app (and/or search indexer) to refresh the index to include photos that were newly added to a folder, by going to the folder in Windows Explorer, and explicitly opening one of the new photos from there with the Photos app.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft has posted some generic troubleshooting instructions for Metro/Modern UI apps:

[What to do if you have problems with an app](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-troubleshoot-problems-app).

At the end of the post is a link to a diagnostic app that can be run, as well.