# Why does thumbnail from deleted photo still shows up in the Photos tile in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, photos, windows-photo-viewer, live-tiles

I deleted a photo on Windows 10 and emptied the trash.

Now, the photo still appears in the Microsoft Photos tile in the start menu. How can I remove it there? Is there a thumbnail trailing somewhere?

I have found some related questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/490232/can-i-select-which-folders-the-photos-live-tile-chooses-from), but cannot find an answer. In some forum, it was suggested to restart the computer, but this does not solve the problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked a question that said you can SET a photo as the tile, did you try that? Windows does cache/store thumbnail photos which it is likely drawing from. Likely in time that'll get updated & the photo will change in the tile. I sense you want to quicken that though, Thumbs.db (hidden file) I think was the File Explorer thumbnail cache, don't know what it is for Photos app.

- [Someone on this question](https://superuser.com/a/1388485/160219) said to close Photos & delete this path: `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState`
- On the same question another person indicated wiping or ensuring Windows Indexing is enabled

Comment: One month later, the deleted image still appeared in the tile. There was indeed a thumbnail in the indicated `localappdata` path. After deleting it, it did not appear anymore in the tile.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a Disk Cleanup and make sure to remove thumbnails (Click the little arrow next to it). Then right-click on photos and go to More->App Settings. Go to reset app and click reset. This worked for me.